# XlsxWriter alignment settings are not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter to create Excel sheets from my Python dataframe. Everything works fine except the alignment settings, they just don't appear in my output worksheet. I would like to wrap the header text and set it vertically and horisentally to the center and I also would like to align column A:A to the left. Here is my code so far:

```
percent = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%', 'bold': False})
header = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True, 'align': 'center','align': 'vcenter','border': 1})
left = workbook.add_format({'align': 'left'})
vjustify = workbook.add_format({'align': 'vjustify'})
wrap = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
border = workbook.add_format({'border': 1})

worksheet.set_row(0, 30, header)

worksheet.set_column('A:T', None, border)
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 12, left)
worksheet.set_column('H:L', None, None, {'level': 1})
worksheet.set_column('M:Q', 6)
worksheet.set_column('R:R', 12, percent)
worksheet.set_column('T:T', 60)
```

Please help me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column ranges in XlsxWriter (and Excel) need to be unique and cannot overlap. From the XlsxWriter [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-column):

> Ranges cannot overlap. Each unique contiguous range should be specified separately:

```py
# This won't work.
worksheet.set_column('A:D', 50)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 10)

# It needs to be split into non-overlapping regions.
worksheet.set_column('A:B', 50)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 10)
worksheet.set_column('D:E', 50)
```

In your example the range `'A:T'` overrides several of the other ranges. So you will need to split out your ranges into unique non-overlapping ranges.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but I have only one line for example for the header and the wrapping, center alignment doesn't wor neither :( also modified my column settings as the following without any succes:

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 12, left)
worksheet.set_column('B:T', None, border)

Comment: If the header formatting isn't working then it is probably because Pandas is overwriting it. See the following section of the Xlsxwriter docs on [Formatting of the Dataframe headers](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers). Also, it would be easier to give a definitive answer to your question if you provided sample dataframe data.

Comment: yes, I have just found that section in the documentation, apperantly I cannot change the formatting of the header, unless I import my df without header and create it again in the xlsx writer, what I would like to avoid as I have several column names :(